# Regex for testing non-whitespace-only string

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have `Required` attribute for some strings in my view model, but that doesn't catch if user types, say,  (yes, whitespace) into the text area. I need to prevent user to submit whitespace-only strings.

I am trying to use `RegularExpression` attribute on my view model's properties to validate the string. I've seen some answers such as [Filtering "whitespace-only" strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921688/filtering-whitespace-only-strings-in-javascript) or [How to validate whitespaces using jquery/ajax in an MVC view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544299/how-to-validate-whitespaces-using-jquery-ajax-in-an-mvc-view) but they don't seem to work properly (yes, before you ask, I am omitting leading and trailing `/`s if I'm taking it from Javscript to C#). The examples at the answers to those questions usually validate only against whitespace, or no whitespace at all. What I need is that I need at least *some* text to validate. Having some whitespace is no problem as long as I also have some non-whitespace string too.

What regex should I use (I am not good with regexes) in my attribute to validate some text that contains *at least* some non-whitespace text?

Comment: 5 seconds worth of googling has several answers, including http://stackoverflow.com/a/2788151/3279876

Comment: @Sami well, I did google for several minutes before posting. if I did find a working solution, why would I post?

Comment: did you determine a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

The Regex needed is `^(.*\S.*)$`. This will allow spaces if there is another "real" character.

In an attribute it would look something like.

```
//using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[Required, RegularExpression(@"^(.*\S.*)$")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

I tried adding `Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)` first with no success, but that is what Microsoft says to do. It didn't work for me but the Regex above did.

Answer (score -1):

You can add these data-annotations to your strings:

```
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter email address !", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

The part **AllowEmptyStrings = false** will prevent you from saving empty strings (like a whitespace)

Comment: it doesn't work. added it, typed some space, and it validated, where it shouldn't.

Comment: Then 
`[RegularExpression(@"^[^\s\,]+$", ErrorMessage = "Email Can't Have Spaces")]`

Answer (score -1):

the regular expression `^\s+$` matches strings that consist only of whitespace.

the regular expression `\S` matches strings that contain some non-whitespace.

Comment: `\S`, when used with the `RegularExpression` attribute, won't allow a string with whitespace, even if it has non-whitespace characters.

Comment: You asked for a regular expression that matches "whitespace only". Duh.

Answer (score -1):

Try this expression: `^\S+$`

Tested at http://regexr.com/3cq34.

Comment: Have you even read the question? Your own example doesn't work if the text contains any space.